# Delphi - CreateProcess - Execute multiple commands

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

I want to achieve the following with a CreateProcess() - call:

1. Change to an svn working-copy
2. Execute svn commands
3. Pipe the output to a file

I try this with the following function

```
procedure TQPortMainForm.CmdMigrationClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CreateOk: boolean;
  input: String;
begin
  { fill with known state }
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);

  //debug
  input := 'D: && cd D:\Qport\trunk\Qport\ && ' + SVN_PATH + ' log > C:\users\PhilippKober\UNIQUE_NAME_BLUB.txt';

  CreateOk := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(input), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil,
    nil , StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  { check to see if successful }
  if CreateOk then
    // may or may not be needed. Usually wait for child processes
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
end;
```

Simply nothing happens. Has anybody got an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Philipp

EDIT 1: I am using Delphi XE - Build 7601: Service Pack 1

EDIT 2: Here is the solution:

```
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CreateOk: boolean;
  input: String;
  path : String;
  cmd : String;
begin
  { fill with known state }
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);

  path := 'D:\Qport\trunk\Qport\';
  cmd := 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe';
  //debug
  input := '/C' + SVN_PATH + ' help > C:\users\PhilippKober\UNIQUE_NAME_BLUB.txt';

  CreateOk := CreateProcess(PChar(cmd), PChar(input), nil, nil, false, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil,
     Pchar(path), StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  { check to see if successful }
  if CreateOk then
    // may or may not be needed. Usually wait for child processes
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
end;
```

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply an executable file when you call `CreateProcess`. I guess you are used to calling `ShellExecute` which is more lax.

You are clearly looking to call `cmd.exe` so you should add that to the command line. Rather than changing the working directory after `cmd.exe` has started, use the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter of `CreateProcess` to do that. You will also need to pass the `/C` option to `cmd.exe` to make it close once the command has completed.

So you need to change `input` to be this:

```
input := GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC') + ' /C ' + SVN_PATH + 
  ' log > C:\users\PhilippKober\UNIQUE_NAME_BLUB.txt';
```

I use `GetEnvironmentVariable('COMSPEC')` as a means to obtain the path to the command interpretor.

And then call `CreateProcess` like this:

```
CreateProcess(
  nil, 
  PChar(input), 
  nil, 
  nil, 
  False, 
  CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 
  nil,
  'D:\Qport\trunk\Qport', 
  StartInfo, 
  ProcInfo
);
```

It is semantically cleaner to use `or` to combine flags than `+`, although it has the same effect for these flags.

One thing to watch out for is that the second parameter must point to writeable memory. That's because `CreateProcess` may modify that parameter. As it happens, your setting of `input` will meet that requirement. In any case, a call to `UniqueString` would be recommended in my view to make it explicit that you are meeting that requirement.

The other thing I see that is missing is code to close the handles that are returned by `CreateProcess`. Close those handles by doing this in the end:

```
//WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); //in case you want to wait for Process to terminate
CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
```

Comment: @David: It is a bad idea to use the first parameter of CreateProcess! You should put all into the second parameter in order to have a "valid" command line argument for the started process. See documentation of `CreateProcess`...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach: The special case of batch execution trough cmd.exe, the documentation suggest to use the first parameter with cmd.exe.

"To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file." (http://goo.gl/9y0gw)