# How to call CreateProcess in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe6

Following the documentation of [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), and [the example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx), i'm trying to call [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
var
   commandLine: string;
   si: TStartupInfo;
   pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
   commandLine := 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe';

   si := Default(TStartupInfo);
   si.cb := sizeof(si);

   CreateProcess(
        PChar(nil),         //no module name (use command line)
        PChar(commandLine), //Command Line
        nil,                //Process handle not inheritable
        nil,                //Thread handle not inheritable
        False,              //Don't inherit handles
        0,                  //No creation flags
        nil,                //Use parent's environment block
        PChar(nil),         //Use parent's starting directory
        si,                 //Startup Info
        pi                  //Process Info
   );
```

The call crashes with an access violation:

> Exception EAccessViolation in module kernel32.dll at 0003B77B.
>   Access violation at address 7671B77B in module 'kernel32.dll'. Write of address 00B47EA6.

Now i understand why it's crashing for me, but i don't understand why [it isn't crashing for the sample code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx), nor do i understand [why it wasn't failing for you David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013251/delphi-createprocess-execute-multiple-commands).

The documentation for `CreateProcess` says that if the first parameter is **null** (as it is in my example, the MSDN example, and the other example) then `CreateProcess` will **modify** the `commandLine` argument:

> lpCommandLine [in, out, optional]
>
> ...
>
> The Unicode version of this function, **CreateProcessW**, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

When i look at the access violation, it's trying to write to address `0x00B47EA6`:

[image]

So `CreateProcess` is trying to scribble over null terminator of my unicode string. There is some debate in the `CreateProcess` page comments if `CreateProcess` will try to *modify* the command line rather than making it longer.

It is entirely possible that my string

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

is sitting in a read-only data section. The string itself has a reference count of `-1`:

[image]

which happens when constant strings come from **constants**.

I can test this by copying the string into a buffer:

```
var
    commandLine: string;
    si: TStartupInfo;
    pi: TProcessInformation;
    l: Integer;
    buffer: TByteDynArray;

commandLine := 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe';

//Copy to writable buffer (including null terminator)    
l := (Length(commandLine)+1)*sizeof(Char);
SetLength(buffer, l);
Move(commandLine[1], buffer[0], l);

si := Default(TStartupInfo);
si.cb := sizeof(si);

if not CreateProcess(
            PChar(nil),               //no module name (use command line)
//          PChar(commandLine), //Command Line
            @buffer[0],
            nil,                //Process handle not inheritable
            nil,                //Thread handle not inheritable
            False,              //Don't inherit handles
            0,                  //No creation flags
            nil,                //Use parent's environment block
            PChar(nil),         //Use parent's starting directory
            si,                 //Startup Info
            {var}pi             //Process Info
);
```

And that works successfully.

So after authoring my question, and researching it, i have answered my own problem. But i'd still like to know what the decent way to handle this is

> How to call CreateProcess in Delphi?

How does everyone else call it? Is everyone else copying the string to a byte buffer?

### Bonus `ShellExecute`

He's how you use `ShellExecute`:

```
var
   shi: TShellExecuteInfo;

shi := Default(TShellExecuteInfo);
shi.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
shi.lpFile := PChar(commandLine); 
shi.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

ShellExecuteEx(@shi);
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637203/why-does-createprocess-give-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-app for a full example

Comment: Using a separate buffer is exactly what the MSDN code and David's code do. In C and C++, `argv` is a writable array of pointers to writable arrays of characters. In Delphi, dynamically constructed strings are writable. You don't need a *byte* buffer, though; ordinary characters are fine.

Comment: @Ian A call to UniqueString is, in my view, the idiomatic way to ensure the strings buffer is writeable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace PChar(commandLine) with PChar(WideString(commandLine)). This worked for me in Delphi XE6.

I suppose they have broken something in string casts as my old code in Delphi XE works without such strict conversion.

Comment: No need for WideString. We can just make a writable UnicodeString with UniqueString.